# PhpStorm very slow and sluggish on netbook, optimize IDE for responsiveness?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I recently upgraded from PhpStorm 6 to PhpStorm 7. Delighted to see all the improvements, but it runs awfully slow on my low-powered netbook. The delay between typing and seeing text appear is often 5-6 seconds and gets worse as line count increases. It is unusable at this stage.

How can I improve the general IDE speed and responsiveness?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

**Edit 2017**: You may first want to try experimenting with allocating PhpStorm some more RAM if available. Do this by

1. Going to `Help -> Edit Custom VM Options`
2. Change `-Xms` and `-Xmx` to be something reasonable for your hardware. I have `-Xms512m` and `-Xmx2048m` on an 8GB RAM laptop.
3. Restart PhpStorm.
4. If you want to see how much RAM PhpStorm is currently using, you can go to `File -> Settings` and search for and enable `show memory indicator`.

**Original answer**: I made some changes to increase the responsiveness of the IDE. I'm sure there are more things one could do, but I found these to improve the performance to well within usable margins. From most effective to least:

1. Disable language injections: File -> Settings -> Language injections. Untick as many boxes as you're comfortable with. HTML was the real killer for me.
2. Disable inspections: File -> Settings -> Inspections. Untick as many as you don't need.
3. Disable unused plugins: File -> Settings -> Plugins. Untick unused.

These changes brought down both the startup time and significantly increased responsiveness of the IDE in general.

Comment: For anyone who activates `show memory indicator` and sees no change, that feature displays in the status bar.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/status-bar.html

You may need to activate this in *View > Status Bar*

Comment: When i set `-Xms1024m`, `phpstorm64.exe` stopped working. Even running from command line didn't help nor showed any errors.

Comment: How you are calculating the Xms and Xmx value - Any specific logic please ?

Comment: Thanks, good hint disabling the intentions, I'll keep them all off to see which differences could make compared to "Power Safe Mode". Inspections are somehow necessary.

Comment: PHP Storm is REALLY a memory eater. do not use it as an IDE

Answer (score 117):

Add these to your `phpstorm.exe.vmoptions` or `phpstorm64.exe.vmoptions` file, at the bottom:

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dawt.java2d.opengl=true
```

Solid speedup to the point that the editor is now actually usable.

I will for the life of me just never understand why people create editors in Java.

Comment: Good god, thank you so much. This made a HUGE improvement to scrolling in the editor.

Comment: Tried a lot of things.. this was the only one that worked for me, enormous improvement in scrolling speed

Comment: I did have to add it as 2 lines instead of 1 line otherwise the fonts were very chunky looking.  Gives an amazing speed improvement, thank you!

Comment: Lifesaver :-) 
"I will for the life of me just never understand why people create editors in Java." - me neither. I have actually searched long for any good Php IDEs without Java

Comment: That didn't helped me. I've tried that, also I've tried to change other options of JVM. I have Oracle JDK (64bit). I've tried to change swappiness  settings. Updated kernel to the newest (ubuntu 15.04 here).

My SSHFS sometimes drops connection, causing PHPStorm not remembering local file history, opened file history.

Comment: Also, I'm experiencing lags making computer almost unusable for few minutes (after few minutes I'm able to summon Xkill by my keyboard shortcut and kill Php storm/kill -9 java process frm console). It happens from 0 to few times a day. After killking PHPstorm alone my computer is again responsive.

I've disabled 1/3 of inspections and half of plugins, Also, I'm trying to remove my mounted directiories/used Git repositories from my project. 

Also I've tried to kill some processes in htop. 

I'm very disappointed. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Holy guacamole. This is a whole different program now.  Thank you for your service to society.

Comment: What does this even do?

Comment: Note that you can add these from within the IDE. Go to `Help` -> `Edit Custom VB Options...`

Comment: On PhpStorm 2017.1 (with IdeaVIM, on CentOS 7.3) the Font setting was set as default, but the OpenGL option was not. Setting the OpenGL option actually made the IDE useful. Thank you!

Comment: "I will for the life of me just never understand why people create editors in Java." !!!

Comment: Just 2 lines of extra options, and yet the IDE feels so different now.

Comment: FWIW, the -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd setting now appears to be set by default (I'm in an Ubuntu 18 VM guest, Mac OSX 10.14 host, PhpStorm 2019.1.3, plenty of RAM and CPU available). Made the other java2d change plus added -Xms/-Xmx bumps - still painfully slow! Unusable. :(

Comment: @Jas thank you, your above code makes my PHPStorm ide scrolling very smooth!

Comment: Is there a Mac version of this? Also what does it do?

Comment: This is super helpful! To use this on a mac, open PhpStorm without opening a project. Then hit Configure > Edit Custom Properties and add these lines.

Comment: Note that this still works great on MacOS 12.12.x, PhpStorm 2021.3.2. Holding down a key would lag to about 2 char a second, now it's at native speed. Incredible improvement.

Answer (score 26):

If you need to speed up PhpStorm right away, turn on Power Save mode. 
(File > Power Save Mode or using "Hector the Inspector" icon  in the IDE status bar). This mode turns off on-the-fly code inspections
This way you can finish what you have started, and later decide what code inspections to deactivate.

Comment: It simply disables the code inspections, hence freeing CPU resources.

Answer (score 5):

**OUTDATED IF YOU USE A VERSION MORE RECENT THAN 2017.1 :**

The most effective way to speed up new phpstorm version is an experimental feature that is going to be shipped by default in phpstorm 2017.1. Until that you can activate it on jetbrains products (webstorm, phpstorm etc.)

Click on `Help` => `Edit custom properties`
Add editor.zero.latency.typing=true
Close and open again the application.

For me the change typing is not laggy anymore.
Other tricks didn't helped me or not in a noticeable way.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing unnecessary files from your project.
I had 3k+ *.html log files inside my project and that slowed down typing terribly when the 'Project' tab was open. (Hiding the project tab or turning off the PHP Plugin does also speeds up PHPStorm, but obviously those are not viable trade-offs.) (I'm using PHPStorm 2016)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, PhpStorm wasn't slow at all - a bug in my monitor driver introduced severe lag, and it just happened that I dedicated that monitor to PhpStorm. If you've read this far, try PhpStorm on a different monitor, it would've saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that it will help to increase the maximum memory allocation for PhpStorm beyond its default.

For mine, it was capped at 2GB. I know you asked about a windows machine, but for mac users reading this, you can change this by opening PhpStorm without opening a project. Then hit Configure > Edit Custom Properties and change the xmx value to a higher limit.

Comment: This is already mentioned in more detail in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to exclude the `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2020.1\plugins\` folder to the windows firewall exclude directories, that will make the phpstorm run faster and indexing will be quick.

Windows firewall thinks that malicious software has been installed with lot of jar files. This solution has worked for me. But I have excluded my project `laravel` folder too 
 
**Possible Solutions**

- Use and older version of phpstorm that your machine fully supports
- Disable the unwanted plugins
- Disable the unwanted `inspections` and `intentions`
- Disable the unwanted browser support by pressing `ctrl + alt + s` then `Tools > Web Browsers >`