# PhpStorm very slow

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I installed the latest version of PhpStorm 2016.3 a while ago. Worked perfectly fine for me, but since a few days it has slowed down heavily. No big projects or files, but the response of the software is impressively slow when typing or using menus.

Does anyone have the some issue? It is strange, never (!) had issues with this before.

Comment: What does the Task Manager show when it becomes slow?

Comment: Ah sorry.. need to mention, I am using Mac

Comment: Using 1,6% of CPU

Comment: The whole UI got very sluggish lately. But I have the latest update installed.

Comment: So it must be consuming a ton of memory?

Comment: yep...890MB currently without doing anythign??

Comment: Never used PHPStorm, but iirc, WebStorm had a little memory usage indicator in the bottom right that let you free up some memory if you clicked it. It could be a leak introduced in the latest version. If you can clear some of the build up, it might hold you until they patch it.

Comment: It would be great if you [collect](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems) some performance data and send it to our support (Help -> New Support Request). It'll help to analyze what's actually going on with your instance.

Comment: Please check these answers for possible solutions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842924/phpstorm-7-very-slow-and-sluggish-on-netbook-optimize-ide-for-responsiveness

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable all inspections and, if need, code style checks.

P.S. PHPStorm was and now is very slow under Linux (currently am using version 2016.2). All its versions were slow. Even at powerful computers with SSD. Jamming and sticking is a normal behavior for this program. It's a pity that authors do not pay attention to it. Thanks for those who are helping to make this program free :) Pay 89$ for the good (as a set of features), but very slow IDE is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a LOT of answers I found online, today this really made my editor extremely smooth again:

Disable the "Show whitespaces" in the editor. Primarily the "Leading" whitespace dots make working in the editor almost impossible.

Inner whitespace and trailing whitespace don't have a big impact.

[Screenshot of my editor whitespace settings in PhpStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFLcm.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).